# Requiring two passwords for logging into a server's terminal via SSH

Tags: ssh, passwords

When I try to login to my server via SSH, it asks for 2 passwords :
one for passphrase stored locally on my system, and the other one for server's SSH password.
I don't know how this happened long ago on my macOS.
How do I replicate this dual-password setup on my Ubuntu laptop ?

```
:~ user-mac$ ssh username@domain.com
Enter passphrase for key '/Users/user-mac/.ssh/id_rsa': 
username@domain.com's password: 
Last login: Fri Jul  9 14:53:44 2021 from x.xx.xxx.xx
[username@server ~]$
```

Comment: There could be several causes, so please share the output of ssh with the `-v` option.

Comment: Your key is passphrase-protected, which explains the first question. Moreover, the server does not have the corresponding public key stored in its authorized_keys file, so that it falls back on password-based authentication. You seem to think that this is more secure than a single password, but in reality your key is not used for authentication at all.